# Javascript filter function return different result in production

Tags: javascript, production-environment

my code is :

```
audio_files = [{id: "78", isProfileImg: "1"},{id: "145", isProfileImg: "0"}];
console.log(audio_files.filter((x) => x.id == 78));
```

the result in dev machine

```
[{…}]
0: {id: "78", isProfileImg: "1"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

result in production

```
[{}]
0:length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

have anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: To start with, consider using `===` instead of `==`. Then, make sure the two datasets in dev and prod are the same. If they are, they should work the same

Comment: Seems like you have no file with the id of 78 in production, are the datasets the same

Comment: @CertainPerformance `"78" === 78` is `false` but `"78" == 78` is `true`. I think in this case `==` is better?

Comment: @Nick Being explicit makes things more clear, and will also show if there are coercion issues. If the data really contains a string for the id, then do `=== '78'`, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah good point :)

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the array length before filtering or else verify your data whether that particular id is available or not.

Comment: Hi, I have checked and I have the same array in both evn but not the same result after the filter function :(

Answer (score -1):

Solved by edit the ID detection script